# Pycharm struck at connecting to console

Tags: pycharm

I am using pycharm version 2019.3 on my windows 10 machine. I had set up my interpreter and I am able to run python code normally. But, I am unable to use the console option. it is stuck upon connecting to the console.. See the image attached below.[image]

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Drop `idea.log` at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com Assuming Run works I would guess either the firewall is blocking connection to the port used by the console process or localhost is not reachable due to a network misconfiguration.

Comment: I am mailing my logs to the above-mentioned email address. I am able to run the console in other projects. But I am not able to run the console only in a specific project. Should I change the setting wrt the project? It was working fine until last week.